# Error loading stylesheet: A network error occurred loading an XSLT stylesheet

Tags: php, xml, browser

I am trying to make google sitemap for seo and it was successfully created but when I am trying to access xml file through browser it shows.

**Error loading stylesheet: A network error occurred loading an XSLT stylesheet**

Here is my sample file sitemap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://boss123.com/sitemap.xsl"?>
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"><url>
<loc>http://boss123.com/en/index.html</loc>
<lastmod>2013-10-01T10:34:00+05:30</lastmod>
<priority>1</priority>
<changefreq>always</changefreq>
</url>
</urlset>
```

(boss123.com is fake url)
someone please help ... 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using any framework or CMS like Drupal or Wordpress? If you're using a CMS are you using any plug-in to generate the sitemap?

Comment: It is worth noting that for search engines the XSLT stylesheet has zero importance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error come when your  style sheet for xml is wrong or missing 
means please check
    http://boss123.com/sitemap.xsl
it is on right place and syntax on that file is right here is syntax for that file 
sitemap.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:sitemap="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>XML Sitemap</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    font-family:"Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Tahoma,Verdana;
                    font-size:13px;
                }
                </style>
        </head>
        </html>
</xsl:template>
```